# Run button on one component and show performance on another

Tags: angular, typescript

I developed a service to run a timer, everything works as expected.

When running the timer on the component where it was created is also possible to view it on another component with it working?

Tried it but it didn't work :(

```
@Input() button: boolean = false;

<p *ngIf="button">{{servicesService.fetchDisplay()}}</p>

<app-services [button]="true"></app-services>
```

With that, all the Services component appears in another component, but the timer does not work.

**Service**

```
  startTimer() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.time === 0) {
        this.time++;
      } else {
        this.time++;
      }
      this.display = this.transform(this.time);

      return this.display;
    }, 1000);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<button (click)='startTimer()'>Start Timer</button>
<button (click)='pauseTimer()'>Pause</button>
<p >{{servicesService.fetchDisplay()}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the service to About component as well [keep it in the other component to control the timer from both places], like that:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesService } from '../services/services.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private servicesService: ServicesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
 startTimer() {
    this.servicesService.startTimer();
  }

  pauseTimer() {
    this.servicesService.pauseTimer();
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid blue 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" > 
  <h1> This is the about component </h1>
  <h3> Click on Home for instructions </h3>
  <p >{{servicesService.fetchDisplay()}}</p> 
<button (click)='startTimer()'>Start Timer</button>
<button (click)='pauseTimer()'>Pause</button>

</div>

<!-- <app-services [button]="true"></app-services>  -->
```

[image]